# How to use sleep inside switch case in java script?

Tags: javascript

Can someone please explain how to stop the switch case using sleep in java-script.

**My code:**

```js
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function demo(x) {
    await sleep(5000);
    console.log(x);
    switch(x){
    case 1:
        console.log('before break...');
        break;
    case 2:
        await sleep(5000);
        console.log('defaultwqewqeqweqw');
        break;
    case 3:
        console.log('Two seconds later');
        break;
    default:
        console.log('default');
    }
}

for(var i=1; i<4; i++){
    demo(i);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by `how to stop switch case`?

Comment: `demo(n+1)` doesn't wait on `demo(n)` to "finish", but I guess you want it to? Is that what you're asking? Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/r9usd32c/ This question isn't really about `switch`; all you need to do is `await demo(x);`

Comment: What you want to achieve ?

Comment: Thanks to all for response. 
I am using async function case2 , I need to wait for response . I can use this response in  Case 3.